# Should AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostId be slot-sticky?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app whose name is longer than 32 characters. This app has a production slot and a staging slot. Their default host ids will hence cause collisions, as explained in [HostID Truncation can cause collisions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2015).

I hence would like to set `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostId` (or `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostId`) with a unique value on my two slots to avoid this collision. Should this configuration value be slot-sticky or not?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Azure-function-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-IDs#host-id-collisions%29) documentation we can explicitly specify host id's for your app settings as below:

- `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostId`  (Windows and Linux)
- `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostId`  (Windows only)

If there are any other restrictions that can be satisfied from the [HostIdValidator](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/HostIdValidator.cs#L8)

From Doc: An easy way to generate an ID would be to take a GUID, remove the dashes and make it lower case, e.g. 1835D7B5-5C98-4790-815D-072CC94C6F71 => 1835d7b55c984790815d072cc94c6f71

Most of the information was covered from the GIT discussion which you've shared.

Comment: My question was whether this setting should be slot-sticky or not. Do you have information on that?

Comment: Yes, by adding few settings related to [swap operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#swap-operations) and [deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#deployment-slots) in app settings

Comment: @14207973 Were you able to find out a solution for this?

Comment: @user989988: Microsoft [still hasn't clarified](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-IDs#host-id-override) whether this should be slot-sticky or not. I've set it as slot-sticky in my projects, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

[HostID Truncation can cause collisions GitHub#2015](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2015#issuecomment-459914657)

> The host ID value should be unique for all apps/slots you're running

Actually this is true only when they share the same storage account. From my understanding, it means that when you use the same storage across all slots of your function for an app name with more than 32 characters (with an identical value for those 32 leading char), you must define a slot-stiky `hostId`.